# How do I relax Gulp-JSHint linting rules?

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint

I'm trying to adjust the gulp-jshint 'fail' reporter to only fail based on situations that would break javascript code when minifying.

For example the two situations I find cause the most problems are

- Missing Semicolons
- Implicitly declared variables

Is there any way I can create a gulp-jshint task that **only** looks for the above conditions?

So far I have:

```
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/main/webapp/static/js/**/**/**/*')
            .pipe(jshint())
            .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'));
});
```

But this picks up many issues that aren't important for minification

---

**EDIT**

I have tried using:

```
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default', {undef: true, asi: false}))
```

but this doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Regarding your Edit: are you sure that those options can be passed in that fashion? have you tried to [create your own reporter?](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint#custom-reporters)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [the docs](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#relaxing-options), the conditions you want to enforce are the following:

> `undef`: This option prohibits the use of explicitly undeclared
>   variables. This option is very useful for spotting leaking and
>   mistyped variables.

and

> `asi`: This option suppresses warnings about missing semicolons. There
>   is a lot of FUD about semicolon spread by quite a few people in the
>   community. The common myths are that semicolons are required all the
>   time (they are not) and that they are unreliable. JavaScript has rules
>   about semicolons which are followed by all browsers so it is up to you
>   to decide whether you should or should not use semicolons in your
>   code.

So you should have

1. [undef](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#undef) = `true`

and

2. [asi](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#asi) = `false`

Comment: I gave this a go (see my edit) but it didnt seem to change anything :( I still get a tonne of failures for other reasons e.g. "Use '===' to compare with '0'", "Possible strict violation", "Bad line breaking before '||'" etc.. all of which I'm not interested in

Comment: @Ed0906 did you see my comment to your question?